# Beginner Dynamic SQL Building

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

I wanted to start exploring using dynamic sql.  I know this use case isn't the best example of showing the benefits of using dynamic SQL, but I just wanted to get a feel for the syntax.

In the query below, all I want to do is create a table using newid, so I can get a distinct table name, then simply select some data into that table, so I can run some select statements on it.  Here is what i've come up with so far:

```
        SET NOCOUNT ON;

        DECLARE @TableName NVARCHAR(40); 
        DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
        DECLARE @guardvar NVARCHAR(1);

        SET @TableName = 'tmp_' + CONVERT(CHAR(36) , NEWID());
        SET @guardvar = 'y';



        SET @sql = 'SELECT  X.CLIENT_GUARANTOR_ID
,X.NAME
,X.RELATIONSHIP
,X.PHONE_AREA_CODE
,X.PHONE_NUMBER
,X.RECEIVE_STATEMENTS
,X.CONTACT_APPOINTMENTS
,X.sourceclient_id
into workdb.dbo.' + @TableName
            + ' 
FROM    ( SELECT    g.CLIENT_GUARANTOR_ID
,g.PERSON_ID AS sourceclient_id
,g.NAME
,g.PHONE_AREA_CODE
,g.PHONE_NUMBER
,g.RECEIVE_STATEMENTS
,g.CONTACT_APPOINTMENTS
,g.RELATIONSHIP
,ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY s.SourceClient_ID ORDER BY g.CLIENT_GUARANTOR_ID DESC ) AS rnum
FROM      MDB131.CenternetDB.dbo.CEN_CEN_CLIENT_GUARANTOR
AS g
INNER JOIN ndw3nfdb.dbo.QV_PROD_Service AS s
WITH ( NOLOCK ) ON CAST(s.SourceClient_ID AS VARCHAR(50)) = CAST(g.PERSON_ID AS VARCHAR(50))
INNER JOIN ndw3nfdb.dbo.ClientProgram cp
WITH ( NOLOCK ) ON cp.Client_ID = s.Client_ID
WHERE     LEGAL_GUARDIAN = ' + @guardvar + ' 
AND g.NAME IS NOT NULL
AND cp.PROG_ID = 683
) X
WHERE   X.rnum = 1';

        EXEC sp_executesql @sql , @guardvar;
```

I know i'm missing something completely obvious here, but I can't seem to figure out what it is.  When I execute this like it is, I get the following error messages:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'y'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
Incorrect syntax near '-'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 28
Incorrect syntax near 'X'.
```

Any assistance would be appreciated on this, and if you have some general advice for dynamic sql, I'd love to hear them.  Thank you.

Comment: You need to learn to debug.  Comment out EXEC, add `PRINT @sql`.  See what you get.

Comment: It's not perfectly fine.  The value `y` needs to be between quote `'y'`

Comment: Look at the answer below.  You need the extra quote `'`.

Comment: `LEGAL_GUARGIAN = ''' + @guardvar + ''' AND ...`

Comment: @Eric That did it.  I was messing up my concatenation.  Is there any other way to get `'y'` without using the quotes?

Comment: String must be enclose by quote.  It's just standard SQL.

Comment: One last question.  My query prints exactly the way I want it to, where I can copy and paste it and it will run.  But i'm still getting an error saying `incorrect syntax near 'y'`  Here is the print:  `WHERE g.LEGAL_GUARDIAN = 'y' 
AND g.NAME IS NOT NULL`

Comment: Just curious, if instead `EXEC sp_executesql @sql , @guardvar`, you do `EXEC @sql`, will it work?  If if works, that means something is wrong with the way you call `sp_executesql`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't right.

`WHERE     LEGAL_GUARDIAN = ' + @guardvar + '`

You're using a parameterized query with `EXEC sp_executesql @sql , @guardvar;` so just write your sql statment as you normally would.

`WHERE     LEGAL_GUARDIAN = @guardvar`

Alternatively you can concatenate the single quotes around the value e.g. `WHERE     LEGAL_GUARDIAN = ' + ''' + @guardvar + ''' + '`. I don't recommend this approach.

To clarify when you Print your sql statement you want to see either of the following

**Works**

- `WHERE     LEGAL_GUARDIAN = @guardvar --Works with parameterized Sql proc sp_executesql`
- `WHERE     LEGAL_GUARDIAN = 'y' --Standard dynamic sql. Potential SQL injection`

If you print your sql and it looks like this it will NOT work.

**Does not work**

- `WHERE     LEGAL_GUARDIAN = '@guardvar' --Filters for a string @guardvar which returns 0 records`
- `WHERE     LEGAL_GUARDIAN = y --Won't compile`

Two notes

1. When debugging dynamic sql you should have `Print @sql` statements to allow you to compile the statements statically to find mistakes like this.
2. It looks like you're creating temp tables. You should probably use `#table` or `##table` temp tables and don't bother with the headaches of non-temp, temp tables and dynamic sql even though you mentioned you're trying to understand the syntax

Comment: So, I managed to clean up the table name. when I run `Print @sql` i'm not getting `into workdb.dbo.[tmp_1E6F86CB-8C4F-4AD7-8D02-AD2333452C16]` which is good.  I can't seem to get my `@guardvar` to work, though.  Here's what I have there currently, and what i'm getting from the print.

`WHERE     LEGAL_GUARDIAN = '+'''@guardvar'''+ '
AND g.NAME IS NOT NULL`

The print return:  `WHERE     LEGAL_GUARDIAN = '@guardvar'`

Comment: @AngusGray I tried to clarify my answer. You're missing `+` between the triple quotes and the variable names. That said you don't need that at all. Just change your dynamic sql to `WHERE     LEGAL_GUARDIAN = @guardvar`